# Execute command when grep finds a match

Tags: bash

I have a program that continuously runs and is piped into grep and every once in a while grep finds a match. I want my bash script to execute when grep finds the match.

Like this:

```
program | grep "pattern"
```

grep outputs -> script.sh executes

Comment: You'll want to save the `grep` results into a variable, then use bash's built in syntax for `if` to conditionally trigger another command

Comment: But grep never finishes executing, just keeps pumping out output when it found a match in program's output. How to save that to a variable?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correct (the "every once in a while grep finds a match" part), your program produces the positive pattern several times during its longish runtime and you want `script.sh` run at those points in time .

When you pipe `program` to grep and watch on greps exit code with `&&`, then you execute `script.sh` only once and only at the end of `program`s runtime.

If my assumptions are correct (that you want `script.sh` run several times), then you need "if then logic" behind the `|` symbol. One way to do it is using awk instead of grep:

```
program | awk '/pattern/ {system("./script.sh")}'
```

- `/pattern/ {system("./script.sh")}` in single quotes is the awk script

  - `/pattern/` instructs awk to look for lines matching `pattern` and do the instructions inside the following curly braces
  - `system("./script.sh")` inside the curly braces behind the `/.../` executes the `script.sh` in current directory via awks `system` command

The overall effect is: `script.sh` is executed as often as there are lines matching `pattern` in the output of `program`.

Another way to this is using `sed`:

```
program | sed -n '/pattern/ e ./script.sh'
```

- `-n` prevents sed from printing every line in `program`s out put
- `/pattern/` is the filter criteria for lines in `program`s output: lines must match `pattern`
- `e ./script.sh` is the action that sed does when a line matches the pattern: it executes your `script.sh`

Answer (score 4):

Use `-q` *grep* parameter and `&&` syntax, like this:

```
program | grep -q "pattern" && sh script.sh
```

where:

**`-q`**: Runs in quiet mode but exit immediately  with  zero status if any match is found

**`&&`**: is used to chain commands together, such that
the next command is run if and only if the preceding command exited
without errors (or, more accurately, exits with a return code of 0).
Explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/53577/linux-bash-syntax-meaning-of-and).

**`sh script.sh`**: Will run only if "*pattern*" is found

Comment: I understand the original question asks about continuous monitoring the output of program, so a single execution of grep and script.sh is not enough. Lars Fischer answer bellow addresses the continuous execution.

Comment: @ASB, you right, I didn't catch that, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to @masterguru's answer, but perhaps more understandable:

```
if program | grep -q "pattern"
then
    # execute command here
fi
```

`grep` returns a zero exit status when it finds a match, so it can be used as a conditional in `if`.